# add and Rcpp file to an existing r Package?

Tags: r, package, rcpp, roxygen2

I have already made a simple R package (pure R) to solve a problem with brute force then I tried to faster the code by writing the Rcpp script. I wrote a script to compare the running time with the "bench" library. now, how can I add this script to my package? I tried to add

```
#'@importFrom Rcpp cppFunction
```

on top of my R script and inserting the Rcpp file in the scr folder but didn't work. Is there a way to add it to my r package without creating the package from scratch? sorry if it has already been asked but I am new to all this and completely lost.

Comment: You can have a look at https://privefl.github.io/advr38book/packages.html#rcpp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That conversion is actually (still) surprisingly difficult (in the sense of requiring more than just one file). It is easy to overlook details. Let me walk you through why.

Let us assume for a second that you started a working package using the R package `package.skeleton()`.  That is the simplest and most general case.  The package will work (yet have warning, see my `pkgKitten` package for a wrapper than cleans up, and a dozen other package helping functions and packages on CRAN).  Note in particular that I have said nothing about `roxygen2` which at this point is a just an added complication so let's focus on just `.Rd` files.

You can now contrast your simplest package with one built by and for `Rcpp`, namely by using `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.  You will see *at least* these differences in

- `DESCRIPTION` for `LinkingTo:` and `Imports`
- `NAMESPACE` for `importFrom` as well as the `useDynLib` line
- a new `src` directory and a possible need for `src/Makevars`

All of which make it easier to (basically) start a new package via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` and copy your existing package code into that package.  We simply do not have a conversion helper.  I still do the "manual conversion" you tried every now and then, and even I need a try or two and I have seen all the error messages a few times over...

So even if you don't want to "copy everything over" I think the simplest way is to

- create *two* packages with and without `Rcpp`
- do a recursive `diff`
- ensure the difference is applied in your original package.

PS And remember that when you use `roxygen2` and have documentation in the `src/` directory to always first run `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` before running `roxygen2::roxygenize()`.  RStudio and other helpers do that for you but it is still easy to forget...

Comment: Glad to have been of help. There are other helper wrappers (and I wrote a few of my own) but I feel it is important for anything more than casual use to _know and understand_ what is happened.  And working from small yet complete examples does that.